# Get permissions for stored procedure in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, security, permissions

How do I get the granted permissions for a stored procedure in sql server 2005?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
SELECT
    OBJECT_NAME(major_id), USER_NAME(grantee_principal_id), permission_name
FROM
    sys.database_permissions p
WHERE
    OBJECT_NAME(major_id) = 'MyProc'
```

You can tweak this to join to `sys.database_principals`, or `sys.objects` if you want too

Comment: Using this `SELECT` command, I was able to find that the *stored procedure* that I wrote has **NO Permissions**. How do I now set one?

Comment: @jp2code just to clarify, your stored procedure had no EXPLICIT permissions set on it, but it would have the inferred / inherited permissions, e.g. sysadmin can still execute it

Answer (score 12):

try (NOTE: works for more than stored procedures):

```
SELECT
    dp.NAME AS principal_name
        ,dp.type_desc AS principal_type_desc
        ,o.NAME AS object_name
        ,o.type_desc
        ,p.permission_name
        ,p.state_desc AS permission_state_desc
    FROM sys.all_objects                          o
        INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions       p ON o.OBJECT_ID=p.major_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals  dp ON p.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
    WHERE o.NAME = 'YourProcedureName'
```

Comment: @gbn, yea, it is "junk" query I use from time to time, see latest edit, I reformatted and reorganized the joins

Answer (score 1):

Kind of off topic, but ... you could [enable](http://ysgitdiary.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-save-object-permissions-for.html) you development db to "remember" the permissions it has had on different objects and keep them during development time regardless of how-many times you drop and create an object ...